# Create time in future swift

Tags: swift, date

I'm new to Swift and not so familiar with date and time classes. I want to make an object of type `Date` that refers to sometime in the future (like several hours).
I'm not sure if this is going to be a UNIX timestamp or not.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Swift `Date` (or `NSDate`) is a class in the Foundation framework. According to the docs:

> The Date structure provides methods for comparing dates, calculating
>   the time interval between two dates, and creating a new date from a
>   time interval relative to another date. Use date values in conjunction
>   with DateFormatter instances to create localized representations of
>   dates and times and with **Calendar instances to perform calendar
>   arithmetic.**

So you'd want to make use of the `Calendar` class to do date conversions. Something like this should do the job:

```
func getDateTimeForHoursInTheFuture(hours: Int) -> Date {
    var components = DateComponents();
    components.setValue(hours, for: .hour);
    let date: Date = Date();
    let expirationDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to: date);

    return expirationDate!;
}
```

Of course it can be changed to work with minutes and seconds instead of hours.

You can format the output using:

```
extension Date {
    func toDateTimeString() -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter();
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

        let myString = formatter.string(from: self);

        return myString;
    }
}
```

Just call the `toDateTimeString()` method on the result of `getDateTimeForHoursInTheFuture` function.

Comment: There is no need for any of those `;` in Swift.

Comment: The entire `getDateTimeForHoursInTheFuture` can be written with one line: `return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hours, to: Date())!`.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes. You're correct. But I think my version is a bit more obvious for beginners.